# When an integral extension of integral domains is flat?

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-domain, flatness

> Let $A$ and $B$ be integral domains. $A$ is integrally closed and $A \rightarrow B$ is integral.  ($\star$)

This is sufficient to show that the going-down theorem. If $A \rightarrow B$ is flat, then the extension satisfies the going-down property.

> I'm wondering if ($\star$)  is sufficient to show that $A \rightarrow B$ is flat. Is there a counter example?

Thank you for your directions.

Comment: In general this is false. For example, take $A=k[x^4, y^4,z]\subset k[x^4, x^3y, xy^3, y^4, z]=B$. This is an integral extension of domains,  $A$  is regular, being a polynomial ring. If flat, $B$ would be free as an $A$-module and in particular will have depth 3, while $B$ has depth 2.

Comment: I don't understand why B have depth 3. Please give me a more explanation.

Comment: Did you mean depth 2?

Comment: Since $z$ is a non-zero divisor, suffices to check $B'=k[x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4]$ has depth one. Easy to see that $B'$ satisfies Serre condition $R_1$ and so if it had depth 2, it would be normal by Serre criterion. But, $x^2y^2\not\in B'$ and integral, so $B'$ is not normal. Of course, this can also done by simple calculation without resorting to Serre.

Comment: @Mohan Why need the third variable in your example? It seems this works fine without $z$, too.

Comment: I thought that a ring extension of integral domains $A\subset B$ makes $B$ into a flat over $A$, for the following reason: If we let $I\subset A$ be any ideal of $A$, then the canonical map $f: I\otimes_A B\rightarrow B$ is given by $a\otimes x\mapsto ax$. If $f(a\otimes x)=ax=0$, then either $a$ or $x$ is zero, since $B$ has no zero divisors, and hence $a\otimes x=0$. And the result follows from the characterization that $A\rightarrow B$ is flat if and only if $I\otimes_A B\rightarrow B$ is invective for all I. You are providing a counterexample, what did I do wrong in my argument?@Mohan

Comment: @Fawzy Hegab | $A$ may not be a PID. An element of $A$ is a sum of $a_n \otimes x_n$ with $a_n \in A$, $x_n \in B$, which is not always written the single term form $a \otimes x$. 
(Excuse me, my English is terrible... )

Comment: @Kitamado, Oh yeah. What a terrible mistake I have done! Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general this is false. For example, take $A=k[x^4,y^4]⊂k[x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4]=B$. This is an integral extension of domains, $A$ is regular, being a polynomial ring. If flat, $B$ would be free as an $A$-module and in particular will have depth $2$, while $B$ has depth $1$.

Easy to see that $B$ satisfies Serre condition $(R_1)$ and so if it had depth $2$, it would be normal by Serre criterion. But, $x^2y^2\notin B$ and integral, so $B$ is not normal. Of course, this can also be done by simple calculation without resorting to Serre.

Comment: I turned Mohan's comments into an answer in order to remove this question from the unanswered queue.